# Why is jquery post not working?

Tags: jquery-post

Dont know what's wrong with the following jquery.
I can't get to grab the the variable `'ltable'` with `'GET'` in my PHP script which is in a div `#dispsome` in the same page.

```
var text = $('#ltable option:selected').val();

$.get('searchnsendmail2.php', {ltable:text}, function(data) {alert(ltable);

$('#dispsome').fadeIn('fast');
$('#sall').fadeOut('fast');

});
```

Just to make the question clearer, I need to use the value of Text in a PHP mysql query in `#dispsome`. I am trying to capture it with $_GET['ltable']. But doesnt work ! The alert is showing [Object HtmlSelectElement] and not the value of ltable/text

Answer (score 0):

use $.ajax my example:

```
$("#edit_client").submit(function(){
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"./../ajax/ajax.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(response){
                $("td#output").html(response);
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

It works.

Comment: Modestas,thanks for the suggestion. I have made the question a bit more clearer by editing it. I need to capture and pass the value of the variable to my php script when #dispsome is invoked